# Concatenate array slices

Tags: rust

I have two (very large) arrays `foo` and `bar` of the same type. To be able to write some nice code, I would like to obtain a read-only slice, `result`, of the concatenation of the two arrays. This operation must run in O(1) time and space.

Array access for `result` must also be in O(1). More generally, if `result` were the concatenation of `k` array slices, an arbitrary array access for `result` should run in O(`k`).

I do not want to copy any elements of `foo` nor `bar`.

This would seem to be easy to implement into the Rust core, but no amount of searching has brought me a solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There isn't a predefined type, but you can easily create your own by implementing the `Index` trait for a type that holds both your slices:

```
use std::ops::Index;

struct Slice<'a, T: 'a>(&'a[T], &'a[T]);

impl<'a, T: 'a> Index<usize> for Slice<'a, T> {
    type Output = T;
    fn index(&self, index: usize) -> &T {
        if index < self.0.len() {
            &self.0[index]
        } else {
            &self.1[index - self.0.len()]
        }
    }
}
```

> More generally, if `result` were the concatenation of `k` array slices, an arbitrary array access for `result` should run in O(`k`).

You can get slice access in `O(log(k))`, if your slice concatenation is `O(k)`, by creating an array that holds the cumulative lengths of the slices and using a binary search to find the actual slice to index into.

This would require a macro, because we don't have a good enough constant evaluator yet and no value generics.

Comment: I would edit the post but because the edit is too small, I cannot. There should be `&` before the `self.0` and `self.1`

Comment: thanks @user25064 there were also other issues that I fixed

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I only required `O(k)`, but I know we can have `O(log(k))`. How would I define a generic function that constrains the traits of the input such that the input must implement `Index<usize>` _and_ the `Output` must implement `Eq`?

Comment: That's not possible, because you'd also need a trait supplying the `len` fn, which you'd have to write yourself... Slices already are as general as an O(1) indexing + known length + ordered type can be represented

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid what you are asking is pretty much impossible if you require the result to be an actual slice. A slice is a view into a block of memory. Contiguous memory. If you want a new slice by combining two other slices you have to copy the contents to a new location, so that you get a new contiguous block of memory.

If you are satisfied just concatenating by copying `SliceConcatExt` provides the methods `concat` and `join` on slices, which can be used on slices of custom types as long as they implement `Clone`:

```
#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Debug)]
struct A {
    a: u64,
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(["hello", "world"].concat(), "helloworld");
    assert_eq!([[1, 2], [3, 4]].concat(), [1, 2, 3, 4]);
    assert_eq!([[A { a: 1 }, A { a: 2 }], [A { a: 3 }, A { a: 4 }]].concat(),
               [A { a: 1 }, A { a: 2 }, A { a: 3 }, A { a: 4 }]);
}
```

Note that even though `SliceConcatExt` is unstable, the methods themselves are stable. So there is no reason not to use them if copying is OK. If you can't copy you can't get a slice. In that case, you need to create a wrapper type, as explained in [the answer of ker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37587849/3347227).

Answer (score 4):

For n arrays, you can implement it using a `Vec` like below:

```
use std::ops::Index;

struct VecSlice<'a, T: 'a>(Vec<&'a [T]>);

impl<'a, T> Index<usize> for VecSlice<'a, T> {
    type Output = T;
    fn index(&self, mut index: usize) -> &T {
        for slice in self.0.iter() {
            if index < slice.len() {
                return &slice[index];
            } else {
                index -= slice.len();
            }
        }
        panic!("out of bound");
    }
}
```

And then access it like an array, just don't go out of bound.

```
fn main() {
    let a1 = [0, 1, 2];
    let a2 = [7, 8, 9];
    let a = VecSlice(vec!(&a1, &a2));
    println!("{}", a[4]);
}
```

This prints out

```
8
```